# Invoking External Web service from SOA Application

Tags: web-services, soa

I am a beginner in learning Oracle **SOA** .
can any one share with me how to call global/external web service inside **SOA** application like "Weather" web service ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very vague. What exactly are you having problems with? Have you started creating the composite application in Jdeveloper?

Answer (score 0):

For calling a SOAP web service you can use SOAP Adapter in SOA Suite.
Follow the steps below-

1. Create a new SOA project
2. Create required XSDs
3. Open Composite.xml, there are 3 swim lanes- exposed services,
   components & external references.
4. Right click anywhere on external references and select SOAP adapter.
5. Enter the SOAP URL of target web service and complete the
   configuration.
6. Add a BPEL component under component swim lane and check expose as
   service .
7. Do BPEL orchestration by using assign, invoke activities.
8. Deploy and test.